# How to block assign value in setter in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have for example property like this:

```
private string foobar;

    public string Foobar
    {
        get
        {
            return this.foobar;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.foobar)
            {
                // here I want to check if value is correct
                if(value != something)
                {
                   this.foobar = value;
                   this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Foobar");
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    value = null;
                    this.foobar = null;
                    this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Foobar");
                 }
            }
        }
    }
```

Property is binded (MVVM) to Listview :
 `SelectedItem="{Binding Foobar, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}`
.

And when user changes value in list, selecteditem is changed and value is set in setter. I code is ok, when user selected incorrect value, to value and foobar null is assigned. But in WPF still selected value is displayed. When I set breakpoint in getter I can see that it return null too. How to refresh WPF to clear selected value in listview ? It shoud be empty like at the begin.

Thanks

Comment: So it works with ordinary values, but not with `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you want to override value assigned by binding in your setter method. This will not work because control will not update on next property change for simple reason that it has invoked it by setting property. To implement validation on your values try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962.aspx) build in mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

i would prefer using IDataErrorInfo and dont use property setter logic. the main advantage is that your property value in your viewmodel and your view are always the same and your viewmodel has the information wether the value is ok or not.

Comment: When user selects position from list SelectedItem is set, and then after checking if (selectedItem != something) ... selectedItem must be null, and I have to set this in setter of selectedItem. Sorry but I don't know how can I use IDataErrorInfo in this case

Comment: i do it the other way. if the user set selecteditem == somthingwrong - my idataerror says thats not ok. if you have a savecommand or something like that, you can check your error property if there any errors. in my way the selecteditem can be the somethingwrong, but thats ok because idataerrorinfo says thats an error.

Comment: I don't have Save command, I only want to have selecteditem null again, when user select wrong value.